# Finding minimal number of vertices which connect a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm doing some graph theory studying on my own and I encountered a problem.

I have a connected graph $G$ of $11440$ edges and an unknown number of vertices. What would be the best algorithm to find as few vertices of $G$ as possible, let us denote that set by $V,$ such that every edge of $G$ has at least one ending point which belongs to $V?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is exactly the Vertex Cover problem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

Unfortunately, your problem is NP-Complete, and nobody has a "good" algorithm to solve this problem in general.
The best you can hope for is that your graph has well-defined structural properties you can exploit in an algorithm, but without any more information, you have to resort to an algorithm exponential in the number of vertices (which, given your number of edges, should be at least a hundred).